# How to run xquery from the nifi flowfile returned from QueryMarkLogic

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I need to continuously move the document from ML content db to Azure blob storage.
I am planning to use nifi to accomplish that.

The problem is how to process the input FlowFile to add a new collection in ML content db.
Hence, it could only process the content db once.
I am thinking of using **ExecuteScriptMarkLogic** processor.
However, I could not figure out how to get the input FlowFile uri.

I am thinking to add a new collection name like "Processed" to the document in ML.
Hence the **QueryMarkLogic** processor will not process it going forward.

```
xdmp:document-add-collections($uri, "Processed")
```

https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/getting-started

[image]

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good technique with NiFi is to add a LogAttribute processor and log the payload and all attributes of the message. If you configure QueryMarkLogic to return documents and/or documents + metadata, then the URI of the document will be in the "filename" attribute of a FlowFile.

If you're updating the document so that QueryMarkLogic won't retrieve it again, I recommend instead modifying your query to constrain on some timestamp in your data, if one exists.